# "Выдать головой" или "выдать с головой"?

Tags: фразеология

Во-первых, было бы интересно узнать происхождение самого выражения, означающего "выдать кого-то противнику" или, как сейчас говорят на жаргоне, "спалить". Почему с головой? А что, можно еще без головы?))
А еще мне недавно попалась информация, что правильно говорить "выдать головой", что еще более странно. Честно скажу, я даже не могу представить этот процесс.
То есть, какое происхождение у этого выражения и как правильно говорить: "Выдать головой" или "выдать с головой"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта:

1) ВЫДАТЬ С ГОЛОВОЙ (полностью)

"Он на допросе может всех нас выдать с головой!" (В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев)

2) ВЫДАТЬ ГОЛОВОЙ (подвести под наказание, навредить)  http://www.xliby.ru/kulturologija/krylatye_slova/p59.php

"П. А. Столыпин, считая для себя невозможным бороться с П. Н. Дурново силой своих убеждений, потребовал выдать головой себе своего политического противника. (В. В. Шульгин)

Этот обычай известен был еще в XII веке, когда с князя за вину бралась волость, а прочих людей отдавали головой, причем последняя выражала понятие О ЛИЧНОСТИ. Отданный головою за долг поступал к заимодавцу с женою и детьми в полное рабство и в работу, которую и отбывал до тех пор, пока не покрывал весь долг. 
Теперь — нечаянно, без умыслу выговорить в неуказанное время неподлежащему человеку условленную тайну значит то же, что «выдать головой».

Answer (score 1):

***Выдать с головой кого.*** ***Разг. Делать явным; обнаруживать причастность кого-либо к чему-либо.*** — А почему вы, Малешкин, впереди машины бежали? — ехидно спросил полковник.

***ВЫДАВАТЬ ГОЛОВОЙ кого.***  У***стар. Отдавать на расправу.*** [Мать:] Ужель ещё не знаешь ты, Что твой отец ожесточённый Бесчестья дочери не снёс. И жаждой мести увлечённый Царю на гетмана донёс… (Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка — М.: Астрель, АСТ А. И. Фёдоров 2008.). 
Однако на этом сайте есть другая версия. [Отрезал.ру](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.otrezal.ru%2Fcatch-words%2F96.html&ei=CV38U-mONoiL4gSrsoHIDA&usg=AFQjCNFCVrZ-neVNJmwhsyE-BDI0YbH_8g&bvm=bv.73612305,d.bGE&cad=rjt)